# Access Project Root Path in Sublime Text 3 Snippet

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext-snippet

I'm trying to work out a way to access just the file path from the root of my project in a snippet.

I can access the full file path with `${TM_FILEPATH}` but I'm trying to set up a file documentation snippet that will automatically get the path to add to the documentation block like so:

```
/**
 * app/Controllers/MyClass.php
 *
 * Class summary here.
 *
 * @author Author Name <name@example.com>
 * @copyright  2016 Company Name
 * @package  MyClass
 */
```

with just `TM_FILEPATH` I get this:

```
/**
 * /Users/username/Code/project/app/Controllers/MyClass.php
 *
 * Class summary here.
 *
 * @author Author Name <name@example.com>
 * @copyright  2016 Company Name
 * @package  MyClass
 */
```

Is there a way to parse `${TM_FILEPATH}` to get just the part I need, or is it possible to set up a variable I can use myself like `${ROOT_PATH}` or similar?

Comment: according to the [documentation on snippets](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html?highlight=Environment+Variables#snippet-features), you can access environment variables.  Maybe it would be an idea to create a simple plugin in Python that will set an environment variable to the path of the project. ([Plugins can access `self.view.window().project_file_name()`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime.Window))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snippets support PCRE-compatible regular expression-based [substitutions](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html#substitutions). The following substitution should do what you're looking for, *assuming that the part of the path you want to keep always starts with `app`*:

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[${TM_FILEPATH/^\/.*\/(?=\bapp\b)//}]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>filepath</tabTrigger>
    <description>path to current file</description>
    <scope>source.php</scope>
</snippet>
```

To break it down, our input is `TM_FILEPATH`, then our capture sequence (delimited by `/`) is `^\/.*\/(?=app)` (`^` matches the beginning of the string, `\/` is the literal `/` character, `.*` matches any sequence of any characters (`.`) of any length (`*`). The capture sequence end with a literal `/`. The `(?=\bapp\b)` group is a positive lookahead, asserting that `app` can be matched ahead, but doesn't actually capture it. The `\b` escape characters before and after `app` indicate that `app` should be surrounded by word break characters (which include `/`). This is to protect against matching a path like this:

```
/Users/username/Code/company_web_app/app/Controllers/SomeClass.php
```

where `app` is in the project's name.

Finally, the format string section `//` is empty, as we just want to discard the match, and leave the rest.

Here is an [example](https://regex101.com/r/fG2rN9/3) explaining in more detail how it all works.